# rss-parser reposts same every time

Tags: javascript, discord, rss

I wanted some help on the rss-parser, So I wanted to make the command send the message to the channel only once, but at a certain time it keeps Re **reposting** the same thing every time and I am not able to resolve this.

```
(async function main() {

    // Make a new RSS Parser
    const parser = new Parser();

    // Get all the items in the RSS feed
    const feed = await parser.parseURL("https://imaginescan.com.br/feed"); // https://www.reddit.com/.rss

    let items = [];

    // Clean up the string and replace reserved characters
    const fileName = `${feed.title.replace(/\s+/g, "-").replace(/[/\\?%*:|"<>]/g, '').toLowerCase()}.json`;

    if (fs.existsSync(fileName)) {
        items = require(`./${fileName}`);
    }
    // Add the items to the items array
    await Promise.all(feed.items.map(async (currentItem) => {
        // Add a new item if it doesn't already exist
        if (items.filter((item) => isEquivalent(item, currentItem)).length <= 0) {
            items.push(currentItem);
        }
    }));
// Save the file
fs.writeFileSync(fileName, JSON.stringify(items));
    
feed.items.reverse().forEach(async (item) => {  

const channel = client.channels.cache.get('980990991865626634');
    
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("New Cap")
    .setDescription(item.title)
    .setColor("PURPLE")
    .setImage()

      channel.send(embed)
})
})();

function isEquivalent(a, b) {
    // Create arrays of property names
    let aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
    let bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

    // if number of properties is different, objects are not equivalent
    if (aProps.length != bProps.length) {
        return false;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < aProps.length; i++) {
        let propName = aProps[i];

        // if values of same property are not equal, objects are not equivalent
        if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // if we made it this far, objects are considered equivalent
    return true;
            }
```

I'm new to this, so I wanted some help with this **problem**.

Comment: (please may you write the title in English too?)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).